# How to make ScrollIntoView work without having to use setTimeout

Tags: javascript, scroll, angular7, settimeout

My app has two parent components, A and B, each in their own modules (modules A and B, respectively).  Component A includes child component C from its own module (module C).  Component B includes child component C (from module C) and child component B1 from module B.  All interactions and behavior between the various parent/children components are working fine.  The problem I'm having is with trying to get component (B1) to scroll an element (elemOfInterest) to top of the viewport in response to a flag (flagA) which component C emits through a data sharing service.

When I click child component C's form submit button from component A's template, I am routed to component B.  But the scrollToView in child component B1 doesn't work without a setTimeout.  Once component B1's ngOnInit lifecycle has fired, clicking component C's form submit button (this time from component B's template) causes the scrollToView method to work perfectly fine without a setTimeout.  I can't figure out for the life of me why ngOnInit would interfere with scrollToView in component B1. Here's my code:

ComponentC.component.ts:

```
export class ComponentC implements OnInit {
  constructor(private dataSharing: DataSharingService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    doSomething(){
      this.dataSharing.transferData({'data':{'flagA':true}});
    }
  }
}
```

ComponentC.component.html:

```
<form class="mx-auto" [formGroup]="searchForm" (ngSubmit)="doSomething()">
  <div> … </div>
  <div> <button type="submit">Submit</button> </div>
</form>
```

ComponentB1.component.ts

```
export class ComponentB1 implements OnDestroy, OnInit {
  subscriptions: Subscription = new Subscription();
  constructor(private dataSharing: DataSharingService) {}
  ngOnInit() {
    this.subscriptions.add(
      this.dataSharing.outgoingData$.subscribe(data => {
        this.onSharedData(data);
      })
    )
  }

  onSharedData(data) {
    if (Object.keys(data).length && Object.keys(data['data']).length) {
      switch (true) {
        case data['data']['flagA']:
          this.func1();
          break;
        case data['data']['flagB']:
          this.func2();
          break;
      }
    }
  }

  ngOnDestroy() {this.subscriptions.unsubscribe()}

  func1(){
    //do something simple, like set html element values, etc.
    setTimeout(()=>document.getElementById('elemOfInterest').scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start', inline: 'nearest'}));
  }
}
```

data sharing service code:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Observable, ReplaySubject } from 'rxjs';
@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class DataSharingService {
  outgoingData$ = new ReplaySubject(1);
  constructor() {}
  transferData(incomingData: object){
    this.outgoingData$.next(incomingData);
  }
}
```

For what it's worth, I've also tried using jquery

```
$('html, body').animate({ scrollTop: $('#elemOfInterest).offset().top }, 'slow')
```

instead of scrollToView but still require setTimeout when component B1 is first initiated for the scroll to work correctly.  Any idea how to accomplish the scrolling behavior without using setTimeout?

Answer (score 0):

`outgoingData$` is a ReplaySubject, which means it emits the last value to every new subscriber immediately. So if `transferData` has been called earlier by the app, this replay subject already has some value (note that `DataSharingService` is an app-wide singleton in your code snippet, it doesn't get recreated upon navigation).

Now ComponentB1 subscribes to it inside ngOnInit. The replay subject emits immediately upon subscribing - right during this ngOnInit execution. At this point ComponentB1 has not been rendered by Angular yet - so `elemOfInterest` probably doesn't exist yet.

Comment: Actually, I included let ``elem=document.getElementById('elemOfInterest') in ngOnInit`` before the observable subscription line and ran the app in debug mode by setting a breakpoint at the subscription line.  When the app paused, elem had a valid value.  Wouldn't that suggest that elemOfInterest has already rendered?  In any case, how would you propose to fix this besides using setTimeout? Use a callback?  Something else?  Just trying to find alternatives to setTimeout.(have been told setTimeout should be avoided to the extent possible, though not sure I understand why).

Comment: Well, I just assumed that elemOfInterest is something inside ComponentB. In this case this element would not exist in DOM during ngOnInit.
However, if it's external to ComponentB, it doesn't have to be the case. If so you might want to investigate the lifecycle of that elemOfInterest - when it is created, when it is destroyed.

If it belongs to ComponentB (as per my initial assumption to my assumption), then you might want to subscribe in ngAfterViewInit() hook instead of ngOnInit()

Comment: elemOfInterest is in component B1 (which is a child of component B).